How do I set up next.js to use webpack?
Ive installed my app with npx create ..., installed webpack library and created webpack.config.js, when Im running it down the app does not use a webpack for assembling.I tried to change the settings in the package.json and next.config.js, but I couldn't solve the problem. Can you help me please?
package.json:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint:write": "next lint --cache --fix",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },

next.config.js:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

export default nextConfig;


